# Issue displaying correct number of item on keyup search input (pagination)

Tags: javascript, events, filter, pagination

This is my app.js

```
search.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {

    //how many student names matched the input
    const array = Array.from(studentListItems).slice (0,54).filter(s =>  s.children[0].children[1].textContent.includes(e.target.value))
  if (e.target.value.length > 0) {
        const noResults = document.querySelector(".no-results");


        if (array.length == 0) {
                Array.from(studentListItems).forEach(student => {
                student.style.display = "none";
                });
                noResults.style.display = "block";
                replaceLinks(array)
        //show ones that match, hide ones that don't 
        } else if (array.length > 0) {
                    replaceLinks(array)
                    console.log(array)
                    displayPage(array,1);   
                    addEventListener(array);
                    noResults.style.display = "none";
            }   
        // Display the initial state if search term is empty
  } else {                  
        displayPage(studentListItems, 1);
        replaceLinks(studentListItems);
        addEventListener(studentListItems);
    }

});
```

This is a project on pagination.

If there's a match from the value typed in the search input, I want the correct number of items to be displayed and the event listener to be added to the pagination links that show up.

So basically in the else if (array.length>0) clause, the replaceLinks(array) function works, but **not displayPage(array, 1) and addEventListener(array)**. When I type something in, even though the array may contain two items, **there will be way more items dispalyed on the page for some reason.** Even more than 10, which is max number of items to be displayed. I don't know why.

The whole goal is to display pagination links based on how many search results are returned (I checked for the number of searches using the **filter** function). For example: if 10 or fewer results are returned, 0 or 1 pagination links are displayed. If 22 search results are returned, 3 pagination links are displayed.

Here is a link to my JS fiddle:
You can test these issues here. 
 https://jsfiddle.net/0nfb34oe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope your example is only for education :) Beacuse, your data are supposed to be come from backend and display in frontend. In your example implements full filtering is impossible, because DOM must be changed in every filter and loosing some data. 
I've changed your search listener:

```
search.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  const array = Array.from(studentListItems).filter((s,ind,arr) =>  {
    studentList.removeChild(s)
    return s.querySelector('h3').textContent.includes(e.target.value)
  })
  if (e.target.value.length > 0) {
    if (array.length === 0) {
      const li = document.createElement('li');
      li.className = 'no-results';
      li.innerHTML = `<h3>No Results Shown Found</h3>`;
      studentList.appendChild(li)
      replaceLinks(array)
    } else {
      array.forEach((item)=>{
        studentList.appendChild(item)
      })
      replaceLinks(array)
      displayPage(array,1); 
      addEventListener(array);
   }    
  } else {     
    arrayList.forEach((item)=>{
      studentList.appendChild(item)
    })
    displayPage(studentListItems, 1);
    replaceLinks(studentListItems);
    addEventListener(studentListItems);
  }
});
```

I've improved your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/518oewda/